# Check if record exist in collection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have controller

```
public function users() {

 $users = User::all('id');

 return view('view', compact('users'))

}
```

Then in my view, i try to check if `$users` has id I need

```
@if (contains($users, Auth::user()->id)
   do something
@enif
```

but nothing happens. How can i check if collection has the id i need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($users->contains('id', Auth::user()->id)){}
```

You need to specify the field where to look as the first parameter.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!